# Symfony 3.4 controller is not autowired correctly

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony-3.4

I have a symfony 3.4 projet with multiple application bundles.
I added autowiring configuration in app/config/services.yml as follow :

```yml
services:
    _defaults:
    # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
    # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
    # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
    # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    XyzAPP\MainBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/XyzAPP/MainBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/XyzAPP/MainBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    XyzAPP\MainBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/XyzAPP/MainBundle/Controller'
        tags: [ 'controller.service_arguments' ]
```

My files/directories structure :

/app/config/**services.yml**

/src/XyzApp/MainBundle/Controller/**AdminController.php**

Here is the tested method in AdminController where I inject a logger:

```php
<?php

namespace XyzApp\MainBundle\Controller;


use use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
// .... more imports


class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function testAction(LoggerInterface $logger): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Hello: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }

    //... more actions

}
```

When I call the route related to **testAction** I get this error :
[image: error DI]

I checked the the command **php bin/console debug:autowiring** the controller is not in the list!

Thanks !

Comment: Please share more details, like the full definition of that `AdminController.php`

Comment: Please share more details, like the list of imports. Which class `Controller` does that controller extend? The same as  all other controllers?

Comment: It's a bit unusual for an application to configure a bundle's services.  Normally this would be handled by a MainBundle/Resources/config/services.yml file and loaded via the bundle's extension.  Having said that I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your approach assumeing you have your resource paths set correctly and you don't have other code overriding your service definitions.  Maybe try bin/console debug:container and double check the controller service is not being defined.

Comment: @NicoHaase I added more detail about the controller. The detail of the other controllers does not seem important in this case.

Comment: @Cerad I double checked **bin/console debug:container**, the AdminController is not on the list of autowired classes and interfaces

Comment: Try dropping the * in resource: '../../src/XyzAPP/MainBundle/*' and adding a trailing forward slash to resource: '../../src/XyzAPP/MainBundle/Controller'  Not sure if that will help or not but it matches the default file.

Comment: @Cerad I have already tested that it does not work

Comment: And is that your complete services.yml file?  autowire/autoconfig is easy to confuse anytime you have a bunch of stuff under the src directory.  Is the services.yml file even being loaded?  Still think your best bet is to do things the 'right way' when using bundles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234297/discussion-between-cerad-and-mustapha-ganga).